# Single page application using angular and node js

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

Hi all I am new to nodejs can any one suggest me some useful reference or documetion to develop a single page application, Using angularjs, nodejs and mongodb.

Any help, links, ideas very much appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

look at http://mean.io/
it had a full stack application generator for exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Take one at a time, start with Angular or NodeJS.  Don't bundle them together to start with.

Then look at MongoDB, and finally Mongoose, which is the a MongoDB driver for JavaScript.